# How to read HDFS sequence file in spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to read a file from `HDFS`(`s3` in this case) into spark as RDD. The file is in `SequenceInputFileFormat`. But I am not able to decode the contents of the file to string. I have the following code:

```
package com.spark.example.ExampleSpark;

import java.util.List;
import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;


public class RawEventDump 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("atlas_raw_events").setMaster("local[2]");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaPairRDD<String, Byte> file = jsc.sequenceFile("s3n://key_id:secret_key@<file>", String.class, Byte.class);
        List<String> values = file.map(
            new Function<Tuple2<String, Byte>, String>() {
            public String call(Tuple2 row) {
                return "Value: " + row._2.toString() + "\n";
            }
        }).collect();
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following output:

```
Value: 7b 22 65 76 65 6e ...
, Value: 7b 22 65 76 65 6e 74 22 3a ...
, Value: 7b 22 65 76 65 6...
...
```

How can I read the contents of the file in spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence Files usually use Hadoop types like TextWritable,BytesWritable,LongWritable etc. so the RDD type should be `JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, BytesWritable>`

Then to turn the string you should call `org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.decode(row._2.getBytes())`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am getting the following error upon making the corresponding changes: `the method getBytes() is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: The Tuple should use ByteWritable and not Byte